# "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" when decrypting with Rijndael

Tags: c#, cryptography, rijndael

I'm trying to decrypt a string crypted with Rijndael algorythm. This type of cryptation apply a padding with "#" on the right of the Key and IV, if they are less than 16 characters long. The string to decrypt is received from a Webservice that sends it, and the Key, to me in XML SOAP Format. The IV is the Mac Address of my machine (that the server use as IV to encrypt the string). When i try to decrypt the received string, my program crash at this instruction:

```
while ((num5 = stream3.ReadByte()) != -1)
```

and it give to me this error "Padding is not valid and it cannot be removed".
I've searched this error on MSDN, and it says that it happen when the IV used to encrypt is different from the IV used to decrypt, but, i repeat, the IV is the MacAddress and it is the same everytime.

This is the sourcecode of Encrypt and Decrypt functions:

```
public static string Decrypt(string strInputString, string strKeyString, string myIV)
{
        if ((strInputString == null) || (strInputString.Length == 0))
        {
            return strInputString;
        }
        try
        {
            int num5;
            int keySize = 0x100;
            int blockSize = 0x100;
            int length = keySize / 0x10;
            if (strKeyString.Length > length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (strKeyString.Length < length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            if (myIV.Length > length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (myIV.Length < length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged {
                BlockSize = blockSize,
                KeySize = keySize
            };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < strInputString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                stream.WriteByte(byte.Parse(strInputString.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
            }
            stream.Position = 0L;
            MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream3 = new CryptoStream(stream, managed.CreateDecryptor(bytes, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            while ((num5 = stream3.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                stream2.WriteByte((byte) num5);
            }
            stream3.Close();
            stream2.Close();
            stream.Close();
            byte[] buffer3 = stream2.ToArray();
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer3);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
        }
}

public static string Encrypt(string strInputString, string strKeyString, string myIV)
{
        if ((strInputString == null) || (strInputString.Length == 0))
        {
            return strInputString;
        }
        try
        {
            int num4;
            int keySize = 0x100;
            int blockSize = 0x100;
            int length = keySize / 0x10;
            if (strKeyString.Length > length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (strKeyString.Length < length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            if (myIV.Length > length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (myIV.Length < length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            string str = "";
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged {
                BlockSize = blockSize,
                KeySize = keySize
            };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strInputString));
            MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream3 = new CryptoStream(stream2, managed.CreateEncryptor(bytes, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            while ((num4 = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                stream3.WriteByte((byte) num4);
            }
            stream3.Close();
            stream2.Close();
            stream.Close();
            foreach (byte num5 in stream2.ToArray())
            {
                str = str + num5.ToString("X2");
            }
            return str;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you give us a link to what you found on MSDN. Searching using both Google and Bing for "Padding is not valid and it cannot be removed" doesn't seem to turn up anything about IV's in MSDN for me.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with test code below - are you sure you're passing in the encrypted string for decryption ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string strInputString = "test";
        string strKeyString = "test123";
        string myIV = GetMacAddress();

        string encryptedString = Encrypt(strInputString, strKeyString, myIV);
        string decryptedString = Decrypt(encryptedString, strKeyString, myIV);

    }

    public static string Decrypt(string strInputString, string strKeyString, string myIV)
    {
        if ((strInputString == null) || (strInputString.Length == 0))
        {
            return strInputString;
        }

            int num5;
            int keySize = 0x100;
            int blockSize = 0x100;
            int length = keySize / 0x10;
            if (strKeyString.Length > length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (strKeyString.Length < length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            if (myIV.Length > length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (myIV.Length < length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged
            {
                BlockSize = blockSize,
                KeySize = keySize
            };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < strInputString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                stream.WriteByte(byte.Parse(strInputString.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
            }
            stream.Position = 0L;
            MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream3 = new CryptoStream(stream, managed.CreateDecryptor(bytes, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            while ((num5 = stream3.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                stream2.WriteByte((byte)num5);
            }
            stream3.Close();
            stream2.Close();
            stream.Close();
            byte[] buffer3 = stream2.ToArray();
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer3);

    }

    public static string Encrypt(string strInputString, string strKeyString, string myIV)
    {
        if ((strInputString == null) || (strInputString.Length == 0))
        {
            return strInputString;
        }           
            int num4;
            int keySize = 0x100;
            int blockSize = 0x100;
            int length = keySize / 0x10;
            if (strKeyString.Length > length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (strKeyString.Length < length)
            {
                strKeyString = strKeyString.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            if (myIV.Length > length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.Substring(0, length);
            }
            if (myIV.Length < length)
            {
                myIV = myIV.PadRight(length, '#');
            }
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strKeyString);
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myIV);
            string str = "";
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged
            {
                BlockSize = blockSize,
                KeySize = keySize
            };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strInputString));
            MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream3 = new CryptoStream(stream2, managed.CreateEncryptor(bytes, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            while ((num4 = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                stream3.WriteByte((byte)num4);
            }
            stream3.Close();
            stream2.Close();
            stream.Close();
            foreach (byte num5 in stream2.ToArray())
            {
                str = str + num5.ToString("X2");
            }
            return str;

    }

    private static string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = "";

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return macAddresses;
    }
```

Comment: The Encrypt function is executed by the server. A few minutes ago, i was verifying the code, and i see that it cut the myIV parameter to 16 characters, when MAC Address with "-" separator is 17. But, i tried to decrypt without "-" ('cause without "-" the length of myIV is the same of the key), but it shows the same error. I don't understand, because the MAC Address sent from the client is calculated with a function that return complete MAC Address with "-" separator.

Comment: Your code will always do that - the line if (myIV.Length > length) will always be true if the IV is greater than 16 characters & as a result will take the substring.

Comment: Yes, i know this, but i don't understand the motivation. If the IV is the MAC Address, why to delete the last character ? (MAC Address comprehensive of - separator is 17 long).

Answer (score 0):

Padding is probably Pkcs#5. Instead of #, pad with a byte value that is the number of bytes to pad.

So if you have 5 bytes to pad, padding bytes will be `0505050505`, if you need to pad 2 bytes, padding will be `0202` .

Comment: I'm very sorry if I don't understand your answer. Surely you've good explained yourself, but my english comprehension is bad and i don't understand that. May have you said that i haft to pad with (length-myIV.Length) instead of "#" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the IV is the issue. It's the password itself. I suspect that the password used by the server to encrypt is not the password being used by the client to decrypt.

The only way I could reproduce the crash the OP was reporting was by passing in an incorrect password to the Decrypt() method. Passing in an IV that was just slightly incorrect wouldn't throw an exception. For example, I encrypted with the IV as a MAC address in caps and using colons, and then decrypted with the IV as the same MAC address in lower case and using dashes. -- first few bytes were scrambled, but by about byte 16 everything was started matching up with the plain text original.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same character encoding as the original string at the time of encryption?

I had a similar issue... the difference, in the end, was how i was passing the data (string) to be encrypted. If I copy/pasted into a textbox, the encryption was different than if i hardcoded into the program. So in short... the encoding of the original data makes a big difference.  While the characters may look the same, in reality they could be represented quite differently (8 bytes, 16 bytes, etc).

Find out how the original string was encoded prior to the encryption algorithm (maybe check on the IV parameter encodings as well.